# Standard Deviation Code Output Error

Tags: visual-c++

I can't see my output from this code I have written. I'm trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a set of numbers from a file. I'm lost as to what the problem is and I won't know if my code is right until I can see output. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare Variables
    int n;
    int xi;
    int sdv;
    int sum;
    int sum2;
    int sum3;
    int mean;
    // Declare and open input files
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("score.dat");
    if (!inData) // Incorrect Files
    {
        cout << "Cannot open input file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Initialize variables and output
    inData >> xi;
    n = 0;
    sum = 0;
    sum3 = 0;
    sdv = 0;
    mean = 0;

    while (inData)
    {
        sum += xi;
        sum2 = sum * sum;
        sum3 += (xi * xi);
        mean = sum / n;
        sdv = (sum3 - sum2) / (n * (n - 1));
        inData >> xi;

    }
    // Print commands
    cout << "The Standard Deviation of the Tests is:" << sdv << endl;
    cout << "The Mean of the Tests is: " << mean << endl;

    inData.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the code takes the `Cannot open input file` branch. There, you don't call `system("pause");` before terminating.

Comment: Could I bug you to take a look at the rest of the code? I'm getting the wrong numbers for both sdv and mean

Comment: `n` is initialized to 0, and never updated. Also, you likely want to declare `mean` and `sdv` as `double`, not `int`. Then do `mean = double(sum) / n;`. Read about integer division in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code I found a few bugs.  You probably don't get any output because the program crashes the first time through the while loop on the line:

```
     mean = sum / n;
```

due to a divide by zero error.
The other bug is that you don't increase (increment) the value of n in your loop, so you always only have one number.

Adding an n++ at the beginning of your loop will fix that

```
while (inData)
{
    n++;
    sum += xi;
    ...
```

But you still get a divide by zero on the sdv when n == 1:

```
sdv = (sum3 - sum2) / (1 * (1 - 1));
```

if you add a condition before the division it will work:

```
if (n >= 2)
    sdv = (sum3 - sum2) / (n * (n - 1));
```

Look into debugging tools like gdb to help catch things like this.

Comment: I tried what you suggested while trying to figure it out earlier and this did not seem to work. The output says both means and sdv are 0.

Comment: another bug.

what are you using to compile this code? there's another divide by zero on the first iteration:
when n == 1, n - 1 == 0, sdv == somthing divided by zero

you'll have to put a conditional to make sure that n >= 2

Comment: Also, I didn't check your math, but the mean and standard deviation will probably not be integers... you will have to use the float or double type to get the math working right. it gets tricky when mixing floats and ints in mathematical formulas... good luck.